# Is there a working version of the TYPO3 Extension Builder for version 8.7?

Tags: typo3

With version TYPO3 8 being around for a while now I was wondering why the Extension Builder doesn't seem to be updated yet.

The GIT repository at
https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/extension_builder
does not show any activity lately.

As the Extension Builder is an integral part of the extension development process this seems strange. Is there a replacement extension for version 8 that does a similar thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After checking with the developer the current development repository for the Extension Builder is located here:

https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder

The main branch is targeted at TYPO3 8.7, while the current version for 7.6 (which is newer than the one from TER) has it's own branch at:

https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder/tree/7.6

Comment: If you are using composer to manage your TYPO3 installation you can use this command.

composer require friendsoftypo3/extension-builder

Answer (score 0):

The extension builder is just to kickstart things. As quite a lot happened with 8.5 and 8.6, it will take some time to integrate all those changes into the extension. However for kickstarting it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Georg. I currently use the EB (and it's merge capabilities) extensively to modify and extend a domain model for a web application - meaning that I keep it synchronised with my source at all times. This worked quite well...in TYPO3 8 I couldn't get the extension to run though (even when disabling the dependency check). Should EB run in TYPO3 8.5?